# ¿Por qué no ejecuta esta sentencia PHP al añadir más código?

Tags: php, login

He definido una función en PHP para determinar si un usuario tiene abierta sesión:

```
<?php
    function logged_in (){
       if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
       return true;
       } else {
          if (isset ($_COOKIE['username'])) {
          $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
          return true; 
          } else {
          return false;
          }
       }
?>
```

En la página de contenidos, he incluído el siguiente código para que, si el usuario no tiene abierta sesión, lo redirija a la página de inicio (habiendo definido previamente también la función `redirect`):

```
<?php 
if (logged_in()) {
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];
} else {
    redirect('index.php');
} 
?>
```

Todo funciona correctamente, hasta que, en el `<body>` de la página, incluyo código PHP que haga referencia a la variable `$username`. Por ejemplo,

```
<html lang="es">
<body>
        <h1 class="text-center">Mi contenido</h1>  
        <?php
        echo "<h4>No hay contenido disponible para {$username}</h4>";
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

En ese caso, si el usuario ha iniciado sesión, muestra ese contenido correctamente, pero, si no, devuelve el siguiente error, en lugar de redirigir a la página de inicio:

```
PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $username in C:\inetpub\vhosts\default\htdocs\login\mycontent.php on line 29
```

¿Cómo se puede arreglar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es producto de que no está definida la clave `username` en la superglobal `_SESSION`.

Asumiendo que estás [iniciando sesión](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) antes de usar la variable, deberías usar algunas de las siguientes funciones que proporciona Php para validarlas antes de usarlas.

**[isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset)**: Devuelve **true** si la variable existe y tiene un valor distinto de null, o **false** de lo contrario.

```php
// Valida si la clave 'username' existe en _SESSION
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    // El usuario está logeado
} else {
    // Iniciar sesión
}
```

**[empty](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty)**: Devuelve **false** si la variable existe y tiene un valor no vacío, distinto de cero. De otro modo devuelve **true**.

```php
// Valida si la clave 'username' existe en _SESSION y hay una cadena dentro (no vacío)
if(empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    // $_SESSION['username'] no existe o está vacío.
}
```

Comment: muy buena respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que tu código de php de ejecuta del lado del servidor por ello cuando validas tu sesión que no contiene nada y la quieres usar para procesarla por eso que manda el error de que no tiene nada en general tu condigo esta bien solo deberías poner en tu `echo "<h4>No hay contenido disponible para {$username}</h4>";` algo como `<h4>Detectamos que no has iniciado sesión por favor inicia para mostrarte el contenido</h4>` en teoría debería de redirigirte a tu pagina porque ya no usas la variable indefinida.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Lo único que agregaría para que la respuesta sea más clara es que lo puede solucionar con una validación `if (empty($username)) {...iniciar sesión..} else {...mostrar los datos...};`

Comment: Esta validación que propone @DjCrazy funciona. Si la incluyes en una respuesta la puedo dar por aceptada.

Comment: Esto es una respuesta o un comentario???